# how to aggregate roundtrip ridership based on the same O-D pairs using Python Pandas

Tags: pandas

I got a large set of transit data with O-D (origin - destination) and ridership. All records are roundtrips. The data can be simplified as below:

```
Ridership   Origin   Destination
   9          A          B
   6          B          A
   7          A          C
   1          C          A
   3          B          C
   13         C          B
```

I want to identify the trip from A to B and the trip B to A as the same roundtrip, and sum their ridership.

The ultimate goal is:

`AB = 15, AC = 8`, and `BC = 16`

It seems to be a typical type of question...but I really don't know how to solve it...Any one have clues? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(df[['Origin','Destination']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)), axis=1))['Ridership'].sum()
```

OUtput:

```
AB    15
AC     8
BC    16
Name: Ridership, dtype: int64
```